# Design: running pg_dump when tables are continuously created and dropped

Tags: regex, postgresql, pg-dump

We run PostgreSQL (v9.5) as a Serving DB in a variant of [the Kappa architecture](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/questioning-the-lambda-architecture):

- Every instance of a compute job creates and populates its own result table, e.g.  "t_jobResult_instanceId".
- Once a job finishes, its output table is made available for access. Multiple result tables for the same job type may be in use concurrently.
- When an output table is not needed, it is dropped.

Compute results are not the only kind of tables in this database instance, and we need to take periodic hot backups. Here lies our problem. When tables come and go, pg_dump dies. Here's a simple test that reproduces our failure mode (it involves 2 sessions, S1 and S2):

```
S1 : psql -U postgres -d myuser

create table t1 ( a int );
begin transaction;
drop table t1;

S2 : pg_dump -Fc -v -U postgres -d myuser -f /tmp/rs.dump

S1 : commit;

Session S2 now shows the following error:

pg_dump -Fc -U postgres -d myuser -f /tmp/rs.dump
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR: relation "public.t1" does not exist
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public.t1 IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

We thought of a couple of solutions, but we don't love either of them:

1. Put all result tables into a separate schema and exclude that schema from backup. We love the simplicity but this approach breaks modularity: our database objects are grouped into schemas by the vertical slice.
2. Write application code that pauses table drops for the duration of the backup. We wonder if there's a simpler solution.

We liked the following idea, but couldn't get it to work:

3. Our result tables follow a naming convention. We can write a regular expression that determines whether a table name refers to a result table. Ideally, we would be able to run pg_dump with arguments that instruct it to skip tables that match this pattern (note that selecting tables to exclude at the start of backup is not good enough because new result tables may be created and dropped while pg_dump is running). This is either impossible or we were not smart enough to figure out how it can be done.

Sorry for the long-winded background, but now I finally arrived at the question:

- Is there a way to implement 3. that we missed?
- Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible using the `-T` option of [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html):

> `-T table`
>   `--exclude-table=table`
>      Do not dump any tables matching the `table` pattern.

The [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) documentation has details about these patterns:

> Within a pattern, `*` matches any sequence of characters (including no characters) and `?` matches any single character. (This notation is comparable to Unix shell file name patterns.) For example, `\dt int*` displays tables whose names begin with `int`. But within double quotes, `*` and `?` lose these special meanings and are just matched literally.
>
> A pattern that contains a dot (`.`) is interpreted as a schema name pattern followed by an object name pattern. For example, `\dt foo*.*bar*` displays all tables whose table name includes `bar` that are in schemas whose schema name starts with `foo`. When no dot appears, then the pattern matches only objects that are visible in the current schema search path. Again, a dot within double quotes loses its special meaning and is matched literally.
>
> Advanced users can use regular-expression notations such as character classes, for example `[0-9]` to match any digit. All regular expression special characters work as specified in [Section 9.7.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), except for `.` which is taken as a separator as mentioned above, `*` which is translated to the regular-expression notation `.*`, `?` which is translated to `.`, and `$` which is matched literally. You can emulate these pattern characters at need by writing `?` for `.`, `(R+|)` for `R*`, or `(R|)` for `R?`. `$` is not needed as a regular-expression character since the pattern must match the whole name, unlike the usual interpretation of regular expressions (in other words, `$` is automatically appended to your pattern). Write `*` at the beginning and/or end if you don't wish the pattern to be anchored. Note that within double quotes, all regular expression special characters lose their special meanings and are matched literally.

Comment: Thank you so much!

A moment of shame for me. I was looking for this exact feature, I read documentation multiple times and somehow missed it.